# C++ std::vector<uint8> filled, but data is not displayed

Tags: c++, vector, boost-asio

Heres my code:

```
std::string message(m_buff.begin(), m_buff.end());

std::cout << "Client wrote sth!" << std::endl;
std::cout << message.c_str() << std::endl;
```

If i set a breakpoint in the last line, start the debuger and lookup the m_buff var, there is some data, but it didnt get displayed.

Heres the Data (from debugger):

```
m_buff  [0x00000400](0x00,0x08 '',0x22 '"',0x00,0x57 'W',0x6f 'o',0x57 'W',0x00,0x03 '',0x03 '',0x05 '',0x34 '4',0x30 '0',0x36 '6',0x38 '8',0x78 'x',0x00,0x6e 'n',0x69 'i',0x57 'W',0x00,0x45 'E',0x44 'D',0x65 'e',0x64 'd',0x3c '<',0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05 '',0x6c 'l',0x19 '',0x1c '',0x04 '',0x46 'F',0x47 'G',0x47 'G',0x47 'G',0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,...,...)  std::vector<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char> >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the data displayed by the debugger is correct, it seems as if you're having some binary zeroes in your message buffer.

Remember, a binary `0` (`'\0'`) is used to indicate the end of a string. So, as the first element of m_buff is a zero, the string has effectively length 0.

You should perhaps iterate `m_buff` and print all bytes as hex sequences - or filter out any `0` characters (and perhaps other non-printable stuff as well - depends a bit on what your exact intentions are).

Comment: I've added an answer that talks about how the OP would write binary data directly to `cout`, if that is his wish. That would complement your suggestions rather nicely. :-)

Comment: in germany we woud say "ich hatte ein brett vorm kopf". thank you ;D

Comment: @Daniel … jeder hat mal ein Brett vor dem Kopf :-)

Comment: Habe erst gedacht boost::asio kopiert nichts in den Vector. Nach 2 Stunden kam ich auf die Idee den Debugger einzusetzen.

Answer (score 3):

Extending Alexander's answer (which is correct), if you genuinely want to write binary data to standard output, here's how you do it:

```
std::cout.write(&m_buff[0], m_buff.size());
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `c_str()` it returns the string's textual content followed by a NUL-terminator.  Your string's "textual" content also starts with a 0x00 - a NUL terminator.  Therefore, seen as C-style ASCIIZ text your string is empty (which is how `operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*)` has to interpret it's argument, as the c_str() conversion prevents use of `operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::string&)` which would have access to the properly `size()`-aware `std::string`.  So - ASCIIZ with a "Z" at the front: nothing will be displayed.

If you want to display NULs in some visible on-screen form, you'll have to choose some representation such as "\000", "" whatever, and move through your string one character at a time deciding what to print.

If you just want to write the data out in a binary form, don't use `c.str()`: you can also use `std::cout.write(address, number_of_bytes)` for binary output providing the address as per `&message[0]`, `message.data()` or even `message.c_str()` though you don't need additional NUL-termination and a poor implementation may waste time and memory creating one, along with `size()`.